# Is $fg\in L^1$ when $f,g\in L^1$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $(X,\mu)$ be a measure space.
Let $f,g:X\rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ be functions in $L^1(\mu)$. ($\mathbb{F}$ is the field of real or complex numbers).

When I learned Riemann-Integral, it was quite immediate result that the integrability of $f,g$ implies the integrability of $fg$.

I'm studying 4 texts at a time now, but there's none about this in these books.

Is $fg$ integrable when $f,g$ are integrable? If not, what would be a counter example and under what condition does this hold?

Comment: In general, $fg$ is not integrable. Counterxample: $f = g = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ on $(0,1)$. Riemann-integrable functions are bounded, but Lebesgue-integrable functions need not be bounded.

Comment: While this implication is not true, there is a nice criterion for $fg$ being integrable: [Hölder's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality): if $f\in L^p$ and $g\in L^q$ for $1/p + 1/q=1$, then $fg \in L^1$. This includes $p=q=2$ and $p=1, q=\infty$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X=(0,1)$, $d\mu$ the Lebesgue measure and 
$$
f(x)=g(x)=x^{-1/2}.
$$ 
Then $f,g\in L^1(X)$, but $(fg)=1/x\not\in L^1(X)$.